# mod_perl (without the perl) alternative apache API scriptable modules

Tags: apache, mod-perl, apr

I recently looked at a project called [lemonldap-ng](http://lemonldap-ng.org/welcome/) - which is a nice little portal front end to configurable authentication backend, and it uses LDAP and perl.

It was close to what I am  looking to develop/implement, which is a (very simple) portal system for our various intranet end-points but it is a little but limited, and I need to extend it.

However after 2 weeks I gave up, mainly because the perl module and class structure was doing my head in, and that I don't know perl, and also that I think that project (not unlike most opensource projects) has limited documentation, and is kind of a pet project for the developers.

Is there is a similarly scriptable alternative to mod_perl that implements the type of Bucket Brigades style content filtering, and also arbitrary authentication filters based on filters and Handlers?

(I dont know any c either, so writing modules like that is also right out)

Answer (score 0):

you should have ask to the LemonLDAP::NG community to help you extending the software. It is a full open project with maybe limited documentation but great responsiveness.